# TfidfVectorizer

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Имеется текст, надо вычислить  `TF-IDF`-признаки по имеющимся тексту. Нашел 10 минимальных весов. Требуется найти 10 слов соответствующих абсолютному значению весов.
Как можно это сделать?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете привести небольшой пример входного `data set`? И уточните пожалуйста вопрос - что значит `"соответствующих абсолютному значению весов"`

Comment: Не дописал, "соответствующие наибольшему значению весов" . Датасеты:     newsgroups = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(
                    subset='all', 
                    categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space']
                  )

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код как как текст, вместо картинки...

Comment: Я не понимаю вопроса. При помощи `GridSearchCV` вы нашли оптимальное значение для `C: 10.0` (`regularization`) и получили обученный `SVC` классификатор для этого значения. После TF-IDF преобразования вы получили разреженную числовцю 2D матрицу. Вы хотите получить индексы максимальных элементов данной 2D матрицы для каждой строки? Но тогда причем здесь `GridSearchCV` и `SVC` классификатор? Объясните суть вашего вопроса, пожалуйста

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить топ самых весомых (наиболее часто встречающихся слов):

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn import datasets

newsgroups = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer()

X = tfidf.fit_transform(newsgroups.data)
y = newsgroups.target

N = 10
# индексы топ 10 столбцов с максимальной суммой элементов (в столбцах)
idx = np.ravel(X.sum(axis=0).argsort(axis=1))[::-1][:N]
top_10_words = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())[idx].tolist()
```

Результат: предсказуемо получаем так называемые "stop words":

```
In [144]: top_10_words
Out[144]: ['the', 'of', 'to', 'is', 'and', 'in', 'that', 'it', 'you', 'edu']
```

Имеет смысл указать `TfidfVectorizer` игнорировать `stop words`:

```
In [146]: tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
     ...: X = tfidf.fit_transform(newsgroups.data)
     ...:

In [147]: idx = np.ravel(X.sum(axis=0).argsort(axis=1))[::-1][:N]

In [148]: top_10_words = np.array(tfidf.get_feature_names())[idx].tolist()

In [149]: top_10_words
Out[149]:
['edu',
 'com',
 'space',
 'writes',
 'god',
 'article',
 'subject',
 'lines',
 'organization',
 'don']
```

---

Как посмотреть результаты работы `GridSearchCV` (исходим из того, что код выше уже был запущен/выполнен):

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, GridSearchCV

grid = {'C':np.logspace(-5, 5, 11)}
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=742)

clf = SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=742)
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv)

gs.fit(X, y)
```

Результат: информация о лучших параметрах:

```
In [150]: gs.best_params_
Out[150]: {'C': 10.0}

In [151]: gs.best_index_
Out[151]: 6

In [152]: np.logspace(-5, 5, 11)[gs.best_index_]
Out[152]: 10.0

In [153]: gs.best_score_
Out[153]: 0.99160134378499443

In [154]: gs.best_estimator_
Out[154]:
SVC(C=10.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0,
  decision_function_shape='ovr', degree=3, gamma='auto', kernel='linear',
  max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=742, shrinking=True,
  tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

Все параметры:

```
In [159]: gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
Out[159]: array([ 0.55263158,  0.55263158,  0.55263158,  0.55263158,  0.94792833,  0.99048152,  
                  0.99160134,  0.99160134,  0.99160134,  0.99160134,  0.99160134])

In [160]: gs.cv_results_['params']
Out[160]:
[{'C': 1.0000000000000001e-05},
 {'C': 0.0001},
 {'C': 0.001},
 {'C': 0.01},
 {'C': 0.10000000000000001},
 {'C': 1.0},
 {'C': 10.0},
 {'C': 100.0},
 {'C': 1000.0},
 {'C': 10000.0},
 {'C': 100000.0}]
```