# Поиск признаков в тексте

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, машинное-обучение, полнотекстовый-поиск, обработка-данных

Сразу к делу:

есть список "признаков", например, 1 - ведение пропаганды, 2 - пролеты беспилотных летательных аппаратов, 3 - проведение тренировок и т.д. (в действительности **их** больше и **они** сами по себе подлиннее будут)

есть сообщения (относительно формализованные), например, "Вчера над городом пролетел беспилотный летательный аппарат "Свичблэйд". (здесь *проявляется* **признак №2**)

Вопрос: каков по вашему мнению лучший способ извлечения "признаков" из сообщений?

Моя скудная фантазия и опыт разработки на python предлагает несколько вариантов:

1. подготовить под каждый из имеющихся признаков какой-то набор
   сообщений и обучить какой-нибудь байесовский классификатор их
   определять (минус в том, что в сообщении может быть несколько
   признаков, например, по одному в каждом предложении или же 1 признак
   будет описываться в нескольких предложениях и тогда классификатор
   будет сомневаться и путаться)
2. сваять что-то на регулярных выражениях, но я в них не силен и не уверен, что это хорошая идея
3. смотрю в сторону полнотекстового поиска, но пока еще не совсем
   понял, что это и с чем едят.

У кого-нибудь есть идеи, как еще это можно попробовать реализовать? что гуглить, куда смотреть? Буду рад любым идеям :)

Comment: Не знаю, вот ссылки кину: https://toster.ru/q/477591, http://mechanoid.kiev.ua/ml-text-proc.html, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274131, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/444907. **Может быть что-то вам подойдет.**
*https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/regex.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы попробовал следующий алгоритм:

- векторизация / токенизация текста либо в One-Hot-Encoded ([пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/773018/211923)) либо в последовательности чисел ([пример в функции `get_data()`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/818443/211923))
- построить результирующую матрицу (размерность: `число строк` x `число признаков`), где каждый признак присутствует в качестве отдельного столбца с нулями и единицами. Для дальнейшего обучения придется разметить такую матрицу вручную или дополнительной программой (здесь можно попробовать воспользоваться регулярками), т.е. выставить все признаки (`0` или `1`) для всех столбцов обучающей выборки.
- построить модель для предсказаний (классификации) - выбрать один из следующих вариантов:

  - воспользоваться одним из [готовых классификаторов](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html#multilabel-learning)
  - построить нейронную сеть (можно попробовать LSTM или просто сетку с несколькими полносвязными (`dense` / `fully-connected`) слоями)

Answer (score 0):

я бы сделал проще... без регулярок, крнечно...
если есть возможность парсить текст по строчно, то лучше начать с этого. потом чтоб убрать "заборность" в тексте, привёл бы его к одному регистру. ну а без регулярок в строке можно искать через find. а дальше сам думай что с этим делать, либо считать количество повторений, либо писать в файл... но у такого подхода есть проблема, к примеру придётся понимать бывают вариации... к примеру не только ВЕДЕНИЕ, но и проВЕЛИ, проВЕДУТ, проВЁЛ и т.д.